# Strange exception suddenly appears when trying to install a setup project, need help big time

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, installation

Using Visual Studio 2010 to build a setup project that installs a Windows Forms application .Net 4.0 C#. It has worked fine for ages but now when I'm trying to install the finished setup file, I'm getting this error message:

> Error 1001. Unable to get installed types in the "Path" assembly. -->
>   Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I have been searching for answers for over 4 hours now without finding anything. This problem just came without me doing anything. Last time I build the install file was like 2 weeks ago and there was NO problem at all. I haven't deleted any reference or any code that have anything to do with the setup project.

How could this problem appear from nothing and more important, how do I fix it?

Comment: can you run the msi with logging enabled? That might give an extra hint: msiexec /i yourmsi.msi /lvx* yourmsi.log . If a binding error is expected use fuslogvw.exe to see which assembly cannot be found. Are you using customactions in your setup project?

Comment: ok this is what i could locate :

DEBUG: Error 2835:  The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog, 
Error 1001. Error 1001. Unable to get installer types in the C:\ProgramData\SysApp\SysDir.exe assembly. --> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Comment: DEBUG: Error 2769:  Custom Action _159E88C9_D15A_4CF4_9EA9_A114632FC831.install did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2769. The arguments are: _159E88C9_D15A_4CF4_9EA9_A114632FC831.install, 1, 
CustomAction _159E88C9_D15A_4CF4_9EA9_A114632FC831.install returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (84:5C) [15:59:26:956]: Closing MSIHANDLE (89) of type 790536 for thread 7208

Comment: @rene: i tried to run fuslogvw.exe but i didnt get any information there that helped me :(

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/5958b64a-6083-4327-bb94-4c3c90626f51/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message in your second comment, it appears that your SysDir.exe assembly has been added as a Custom Action with the InstallerClass property set to true, but either no installer classes could be found in the exe or the exe could not be loaded due to missing dependencies.

You can see the list of Custom Actions by right-clicking on the installer project, selecting View and then Custom Actions.

If your exe does not can an installer class, then you can remove it from the list of custom actions.

If it does contain an installer class, then the issue is going to be missing dependencies. If fuslogvw doesn't work for you (it has always helped resolve this kind of issue for us), you can carefully review the list of references in the exe's project and compare them to what is listed in the installer project.

The other trick that we use is to examine the install directory while the error message is displayed on the screen. We can often see that DLLs are missing by doing this, usually because the path was entered incorrectly in the DLL entry within the installer project or because a condition was set incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same error today. For me it was the project type of the class library.

I noticed that the pucture on the guide I was following had selected **Class Library (.NET Framework)** instead of just **Class Library**.

Creating the correct project type fixed the error.

https://nhvu1988.com/posts/how-to-create-msi-installer-using-vs-installer/